# How to grep all files beside current dir, parent dir and one definded?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I have a folder with the following files / folders:

```
.test
README.md
/dist
/src
```

I want to grep all files beside `dist`. So the result should look like:

```
.test
README.md
/src
```

When I do

```
ls -a | grep -v dist
```

it will remove dist. But `.` and `..` are present. However I require the `-a` to get files with dot prefix.

When I try to add `ls -a | grep -v -e dist -e . -e ..` there is no output.

Why will `-e .` remove all files? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `find` with `-not` option instead of error prone `ls | grep`:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name dist
```

---

btw just for resolving your attempt, correct `ls | grep` would be:

```
ls -a | grep -Ev '^(dist|\.\.?)$'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, you can do :

```
shopt -s extglob
echo .[^.]* !(dist)
```